# Does APC cache .ini files?

Tags: php, apc, ini

I am deciding whether or not to use .ini format vs. standard PHP variables/constants in a file holding my app's configuration information. One of my considerations is APC's ability to cache the ini file. If it can, I assume it will speed up my app, as well as reduce reading the config file from the disk on each page load...

Comment: You can manually create a read through cache for an ini file.

Comment: Keep the PHP variables format, it'll be automatically cached by APC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not normally. APC only caches files which are loaded and executed as PHP code. `.ini` files are not PHP code, so they are not cached automatically.

Your application can store anything it wants in the APC variable cache, though, including the contents of the `.ini` file.